# Modeling product orders in Django

Tags: django, django-models, foreign-keys, many-to-one

I have an order of a certain list of products, and I need to model this in Django.

Each order has properties:

```
id
email
total_price
line_items
```

line_items is a dictionary of products and the number of instances of that product required.

Product is a separate model describing a class of products.

I need a many-to-many relationship between Product and Order because each product could be part of many orders, but each order could have many products - how does this look in my fields given that I could have an order that has 3 instances of one product, 2 of another etc...?

Comment: Shouldn't this be a many-to-many, by using a one-to-many you thus basically say that each order has exactly *one* product (or if we reverse the relation, that every product has exactly one order).

Comment: Yes you're right!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> `line_items` is a dictionary of products and the number of instances of that product required.

I would suggest *not* to store this in a dictionary. In a relational database, one typically stores this in a different table over multiple records. The advantage of this, is that it is easy to *query*. For example to generate a list of all orders that contain a certain product, or contain a certain product with a quantity higher than 50.

We thus typically have three tables:

```
+-------+  1    N  +--------------+  N    1  +---------+
| Order |----------| OrderProduct |----------| Product |
+-------+          +--------------+          +---------+
| email |          | quantity     |
+-------+          +--------------+
```

We thus have three models: `Order`, `OrderProduct` and `Product`, for example:

```
Order(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField()

Product(models.Model):
    # ...
    pass

OrderProduct(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('order', 'product')
```

We thus can construct an order like:

```
product1 = Product.objects.create()
product2 = Product.objects.create()
my_order = Order.objects.create(email='foo@bar.com')
OrderProduct.objects.create(product=product1, order=my_order)
OrderProduct.objects.create(product=product2, order=my_order, quantity=14)
```

So here we constructed two products and one order, and we added two `OrderProduct`s to this order, one for `product1`, and one for `product2` with a quantity of `14`.

Comment: how an order can be created with bulk item/product? is it possible with this model structure? say, i need to create an order with multiple product/item, can i go with this model structure? @Willem Van Onsem

Comment: @RTan: you just create `OrderProduct`s in bulk, so something like `OrderProduct.objects.bulk_create(list_of_orderproducts)`.